# WCF server/client conected clients checking value for server

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

Now I have another problem with WCF server/client.

I have a method:

```
bool spr_wiersz(int wiersz, int kolumna) //check_row(int row, int column)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (i != kolumna)
                {
                    //if(grid(row,i)==grid[row,column]
                    if (tablica[wiersz, i] == tablica[wiersz, kolumna]) 
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

And I want send every one value to clients and they will check it and return true, or false to server.

```
ex.
client 1 compare for i=0
client 2 compare for i=1
client 3 compare for i=2
client 1 compare for i=3
client 2 compare for i=4
......
```

To send something to everyone clients I use :

```
subscribers.ForEach(delegate(ImessageCallback callback)
            {
                if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                {


                }
            });
```

I hevan't any idea how conect this ;/
And another problem is, how send grid to client to compare value.

Comment: so you plan to send request to "all" possible clients from the server and retrieve some value back to the server - one by one?

Comment: yes, 
I need to do, sudoku which will be generate using clients. And server will return generated grid. I hevan't any idea how in another way use clients to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem :)
it almost work properly.

```
bool spr_wiersz(int wiersz, int kolumna) 
        {
            wys_tab();
            Console.WriteLine("wiersz: {0}, kolumna: {1}", wiersz, kolumna);
            int i_wiersz=0;
            bool[] result = new bool[9];
            while (i_wiersz < 9)
            {
                subscribers.ForEach(delegate(ImessageCallback callback)
                {
                    if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("wiersz: {0}, kolumna: {1}, i: {2}", wiersz, kolumna, i_wiersz);
                        result[i_wiersz] = callback.spr_wiersz(wiersz, kolumna, i_wiersz);
                        i_wiersz++;
                    }
                });
                for (int j = 0; j < i_wiersz; j++)
                {
                    if (result[j] == false)
                    {
                        return false;

                    }
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
```

It's work good only for 1,3 or 9 clients. For other number of clients this doesn't work yet.